# How to prevent VS Code from restoring terminal panel size when the explorer panel is closed

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just switched to a new computer and did a fresh install of VS Code and cannot figure out how to minimize the explorer sidebar (or search, extensions, etc.) while keeping terminal panel size maximized (opened at the size I like it). I did not experience this in the past and vividly remember being able to open and close / minimize and maximize any overlays / panels without affecting other overlays / panels.

Here is an example of the behavior I am seeing.

[image: Example of VS Code minimizing terminal panel when the explorer sidebar is closed]

I tried looking through the settings but honestly don't know what specific setting I am looking for, and looking through stack overflow questions seems to be people mainly asking how to close the terminal or expand it - both are things I am aware of - I am more interested in removing the specific headache of not needing to reopen the terminal when I already opened it and did not want it to be closed.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

---

Output of `Help: About` command run in the command pallet:

```
Version: 1.85.1 (Universal)
Commit: 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2
Date: 2023-12-13T09:48:06.308Z
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 25551756
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 23.2.0
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. I can reproduce this on VS Code 1.85.2, but I cannot reproduce it on the latest insiders. Can you please also try installing the latest VS Code insiders and seeing if this happens there as well?

Comment: Using the latest VS Code insiders seems to work! I added the output from `Help: About`to my original question. I can use the insiders build for now, but I am still curious as to why it does not work as I would prefer in the standard version. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue doesn't reproduce in 1.86-insiders, so I'd suggest that you just sit tight and wait for 1.86 stable to release. It should release by the end of January 2024. As for why this happens, I haven't got the foggiest idea. I made a feeble attempt to look for a matching issue ticket and didn't find one.

Comment: Thanks! I'll continue to use insiders for now; seems to do what I need!